# Filtering by Columns DataTables with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

In the [DataTables plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library](http://www.datatables.net/index):

Is there a way to:

1. Tell the **Search all columns** textbox how to focus specific text on certain columns, or
2. Create textbox search fields instead of the drop down lists like shown below?

Like, in the **Search all columns** textbox, use the text "c0:ge,c1:net" to return all combinations of **Rendering engine** like `%ge%` and **Browser** like `%net%`.

This is one of our requirements on a project I am working on. If we can't do this with the [DataTables plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library](http://www.datatables.net/index), we may be forced to ditch the whole tool to roll our own.

[DataTables.net::Live example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh: The **Column** fields for some of these returned items are all unique, so those drop down lists would be really large and unhelpful.

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html ??

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, @davidkonrad. Thank you!